# Using VirtualHost directive on a VPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I am trying to figure out why I cannot use the VirtualHost Directive on my client's VPS hosting account. No matter how I define the directive I always get a 500 internal server error.

I tired asking the hosting company for assistance and they replied with "mod_rewrite" is enabled on your account. Not very helpful.

Does this have to do with it being a Virtual Private Server?

Here's what I am using:

```
##Start Virtual Host

NameVirtualHost x.x.x.x

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x>

##Define Rewrite Map
RewriteMap categorymap txt: categorymap.txt
RewriteMap rangemap txt: rangemap.txt

</VirtualHost>

##End Virtual Host
```

Any insights or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName` are required in a `<virtualhost>` section. What does the error log say (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`)?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to that on the server or via cPanel. Looked all over. But I've gotten some help form my client's hosting company so I should be able to solve this pretty soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in a simple rewrite rule instead of RewriteMAP and test

Not sure if it will cause an issue but remove the whitespace after txt: i.e:

```
RewriteMap categorymap txt:categorymap.txt
```

Comment: I have several rewrite rules that work. I've never tried to define a VirtualHost before so maybe I am putting it in the wrong file? Currently have my <VirtualHost> in the .htaccess file and I don't think it should be there. Couldn't find the info on the Apache site on what file/where the VirtualHost definition needs to be in. Thanks